# Dual parameters for same value

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

Is it possible to have 2 report parameters set the same actual parameter? For example, the user should either be able to type in an ID, or select it from a dropdown list - for the query to then take that id and run the proc for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One parameter will be displayed just once. So it should be either textbox or dropdown.

But you can create Param_1 for ID, Param_2 for dropdown list and hidden Param_3 with Value=IIF(Parameters!Param_2.Value = nothing, Parameters!Param_1.Value, Parameters!Param_2.Value)